# module 'api' has no attribute error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, attributes, tweepy

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'api' has no attribute 'get_user_id'
```

I am getting such an error. I tried many things but couldn't. I need help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: The "api" I am trying to import is an external module. "api" is not a package I created. i try to import but i getting this error. how can i solve this problem?

```
import api
import tweepy

users = {}

keys = open("keystwitter.txt", 'r')

CONSUMER_KEY = keys.readline().strip()
CONSUMER_SECRET = keys.readline().strip()
ACCESS_TOKEN = keys.readline().strip()
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = keys.readline().strip()

TwitterAuth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
TwitterAuth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

tweeter = tweepy.API(TwitterAuth)

StinkyChesse = ['mandzio', 'ewroon', 'klaudiacroft']


def initialize():
    file = open("users.txt", "r")
    for data in file:
        user_name = data.strip()
        print(user_name)
        user_id = api.get_user_id(user_name)
        follows = api.get_all_follows(user_id)
        users[user_name] = [user_id, follows]
    print("Bot Launched")
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a tree of your project folder? Maybe a bit more info on where the error occurs or a stack trace of the error might help too.

Comment: i did add. u can see. thanks for ur comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. The error message means that the thing you are trying to use is not actually available to use. There are any number of possible reasons for that; it is impossible to say any more because we cannot see *what you are trying to do* unless you actually **show us**. Telling us that you "tried many things but couldn't" is not useful; we are not trying to give help only to the people who "deserve" it, but instead we are trying to *understand what the actual problem is*. "I need help" is [not answerable](/q/284236).

Comment: @Liferafter what do you think? `python -m pip install api` not the package I created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `api` you're importing but this is not how Tweepy works.

The `api` object that you see in examples is the object returned by the `tweepy.API()` method.

So remove the `api` import and replace this line:

```py
tweeter = tweepy.API(TwitterAuth)
```

By this line:

```py
api = tweepy.API(TwitterAuth)
```

Or keep `tweeter` and change the calls in the rest of your code.